# SwiftUI 2 matchedGeometryEffect: order of modifiers

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been breaking my brains on creating a desired matchedGeometryEffect with SwiftUI 2. During this learning process, something passed my path that I really can't explain. I'll show an example.

I try to create a List -> Detail transition, with an effect commonly called "Hero" effect. The profile picture of the list view transitions to the big banner on the detail view.

To accomplish this, I have created two KFImages (KF = Kingfisher, a package I use for conveniently downloading and caching images) with several modifiers:

List View:

```
if !isProductDetailViewPresented {
   KFImage(store.results.first?.images?.first?.url)
      .resizable()
      .cornerRadius(30)
      .scaledToFill()
      .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image.testprod", in: animationNamespace!, anchor: .center, isSource: !isProductDetailViewPresented)
      .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
      .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
      .zIndex(999)
}
```

Detail View:

```
if isProductDetailViewPresented {

...

    KFImage(product?.images?.first?.url)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image.testprod", in: animationNamespace!, anchor: .center, isSource: isProductDetailViewPresented)
        .frame(height: 300)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))

...

}
```

...this *nearly* worked; somehow, my Image won't constrain to the `.frame(width: 60, height: 60)`. Instead, it stretches to fit the image into the view, making the width bigger than 60. The height stays at 60 though.

To fix this, I figured; maybe this `.frame()` modifier should be placed before the `.matchedGeometryEffect()` modifier. But when I do that, only the position of the two images transitions; not the size. This makes me think that the `.matchedGeometryEffect()` modifiers consider the frames 'fixed' to the placement of the `.frame()` modifiers before the `.matchedGeometryEffect()` modifiers.

This is strange, as several examples on the internet show code in which `.frame()` is called before `.matchedGeometryEffect()`, like [here](https://kavsoft.dev/SwiftUI_2.0/Hero_Animation/) (search for  `.matchedGeometryEffect()`, there are only 2) and [here](https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part2/) (section "Follow the Follower").

Two questions:

1. How come that mine works only when I call `.frame()` *after* `.matchedGeometryEffect()`, while the online sources do the inverse?
2. How does `.matchedGeometryEffect()` handle the order of modifiers? What should I take into account?

Honestly, I am having quite a bad time figuring this API out. I hope you guys can clear things up for me. :)

Comment: Did you ever have this clarified Jaap? :) It could just be me who asked your question tonight.